# Check object type in Polymer Element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm have a polymer element whose model may be one of two classes (technically one of two subclasses of a common superclass).  I'm looking for my element template to be slightly different depending on which of the two classes the model is.  Something like this:

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-element">
<template>
    {{model.runtimeType}} <!-- sanity check -->
    {{model.commonProperty}}
    <template if="{{model is Foo}}">
      {{model.fooSpecificProperty}}
    </template>
    <template if="{{model is Bar}}">
      {{model.barSpecificProperty}}
    </template>
</template>
<script type="application/dart" src="my-element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

What I'm finding is that both of the if templates are displaying, as though both `model is Foo` and `model is Bar` are returning true.  For each type of model, I see that the `{{model.runtimeType}}` is printing `Foo` and `Bar` as appropriate.

I've also tried changing the if conditions to other things such as `{{model.runtimeType.toString() == 'Foo'}}`, but I can't seem to find the right condition to properly sort out my model types.

In a Dart Polymer element, what is the correct way to detect and filter based on the type of an object?

EDIT: Also noticing that both `{{model is Foo}}` and `{{model is! Foo}}` seem to return true as a conditional when used in Polymer, but work as expected inside a .dart file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important not to use `toString()` here, since it will not work when using dart2js with minification. Similar to the other suggestions, here are two ideas that should work even with obfuscation/minification.

```dart
<polymer-element name="x-tag">
<template>
    <!-- idea #1 -->
    <template if="{{model.runtimeType == fooType}}"> ...

    <!-- idea #2 -->
    <template if="{{isFoo}}"> ...
```

and

```dart
@CustomTag(x-tag)
class XTag extends PolymerElement {
  // idea #1
  Type get fooType => Foo;

  // idea #2
  @observable bool isFoo;
  @ObserveProperty('model')
  updateIsFoo() { isFoo = model is Foo; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Foo`/`Bar` (of type `Type` is not recognized/available in Polymer expressions therefore `is` or `is!` cannot work.

```dart
model.runtimeType.toString() == 'Bar'
```

should work though. I'll investigate.

What I got working is:

on `my-element`

```dart
String asString(value) {
  return value.runtimeType.toString();
}
```

```dart
  <template if="{{asString(model) == 'Foo')}}">
    {{model.fooSpecificProperty}}
  </template>
  <template if="{{asString(model) == 'Bar'}}">
    {{model.barSpecificProperty}}
  </template>
```

also working

```dart
class Base {
  String commonProperty = 'common';

  @override
  String toString() => runtimeType.toString();
}
```

```dart
  <template if="{{model.toString() == 'Foo')}}">
    <div style="border: solid 1px red;">{{model.fooSpecificProperty}}</div>
  </template>
  <template if="{{model.toString() == 'Bar'}}">
    <div style="border: solid 1px green;">{{model.barSpecificProperty}}</div>
  </template>
```

Comment: I suppose that makes sense about `Foo`/`Bar` though I find myself wondering why both `is` and `is!` are evaluating to true (seems to me though should evaluate to false, or better yet, throw a helpful error.

Comment: You are right. And this should work `{{model.runtimeType.toString() == 'Foo'}}`

Comment: weird `model.runtimeType.toString()` used as sanity check doesn't print anything.

Comment: Glad to see the bug reports. I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong or if Polymer Dart was having issues.  Happy to know it wasn't just me.

Comment: Note that model.runtimeType.toString() can change under minification/obfuscation (see bug for details)

Answer (score 0):

In light of the Polymer bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20980, it seems that right now the best way to do this is a workaround.  The cleanest workaround I've been able to find is

## my-element.html

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-element">
<template>
    {{model.runtimeType}} <!-- sanity check -->
    {{model.commonProperty}}
    <template if="{{model.type == 'Foo'}}">
      {{model.fooSpecificProperty}}
    </template>
    <template if="{{model.type == 'Bar'}}">
      {{model.barSpecificProperty}}
    </template>
</template>
<script type="application/dart" src="my-element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

## model_superclass.dart

```dart
abstract class ModelSuperclass {
  var commonProperty;
  String get type => this.runtimeType.toString();
}
```

In the future, once the bug is resolved, the best way to accomplish this will be to use

```dart
<template if="{{model.runtimeType.toString() == 'Foo'}}">
```